# how to install aircrack ng on ubuntu 17.04

Tags: software-installation

I don't know how to install aircrack-ng I have downloaded its latest version.
I am new to use ubuntu.So,please respond forward to my question

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu. Please add some information to your question like what did you try, where did you fail ? Installing aircrack-ng is relatively easy compared to using it. Maybe you should first learn some basics ...

Comment: "I am new to use ubuntu." so why do you feel the need to download it and not use the one that is already in the software center? "I don't know how to install aircrack-ng" sorry, but that does not bode well if installing already is an issue ... aircrack-ng is not a tool for a beginner. FAR from it.

Answer (score 1):

to install it on my 16.04 (LTS) i'd use
`sudo apt install aircrack-ng` which I tried & it installed fine.

I use `apt` (or `apt-get`) as they download whatever is required & then `dpkg` install.  `dpkg` is used to install; but it assumes you've already grabbed required dependencies, which is why apt|apt-get is easier.

Comment: I used `apt depends aircrack-ng` & for my box it has 10 required deps; meaning `dpkg -i` install would not have worked unless all these were already installed.

Comment: if you've downloading it (say `aircrack--version-info.deb`) the command to install the .deb file you downloaded is `sudo dpkg -i aircrack--version-info` which assumes its located in your working-directory (current directory).
I used `apt search aircrack-ng` to show version(s) available in my enabled repositories, and `sudo apt show aircrack-ng` to display info about the package ... which told me it's in UNIVERSE repo.  on my system UNIVERSE is enabled; if its not on yours you'll need to enable it first.  If the `apt search` revealed no results, it's probably not enabled.